# How to randomize image array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, image, random

I am after a little help here. I need to randomize an image array's order.

For example, if I have 3 images, I need them to reload each time in a different order.

Also, this is the instructions given to me on how to implement the code:

```
If this is PHP code, use a return statement to send your output to the block. For example:
$my_output = 'Hello, world.';
return $my_output;
```

My current code is HTML, and goes like this:

```
<div class="ad">

<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="myimagesdirectpath/img.png"      alt="linkedsitename" /></a>

<br />
<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="myimagesdirectpath/img.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>

<br />
<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="myimagesdirectpath/img.png"      alt="linkedsitename" /></a>

</div>
```

What I need to do is somehow turn my HTML code into a PHP code that allows the images order to be randomized, while maintaining the original instructions to "Use an output statement" to send my code to the sidebar.

Thanks! and I wish I knew more

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add `homework` to the tag list.

Comment: It sounds like you should start with the PHP [tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php), and work from there.

Comment: put "array random" in the php manual search box and that would be a good start.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need a solution before really understanding the PHP basics, here it is:

```
<?php
$images =   array(
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="myimagesdirectpath/img.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>',
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="myimagesdirectpath/img.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>',
            '<a href="http://www.linkedsite.com/" target="_blank"><img src="myimagesdirectpath/img.png" alt="linkedsitename" /></a>'
        );

shuffle($images); // Randomize images array
return '<div class="ad">'.implode('<br />', $images).'</div>';
?>
```

But to be honest the suggestion is always to read some PHP tutorial like [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php).

Comment: Well, thanks. But as I said I suggest reading a tutorial before starting any PHP. Having a solution is always a good point to start understanding something.

Comment: +1 because it do not support -1 if someone comes with the right solution. It doesn't matter if this is a homework or not!

Comment: Thank you Satoshi! How do I use a return statement with this code? I will also check out some PHP tutorials.

Comment: So this is what I tried to allow the return code. I believe I do not need to wrap the code in <?php ?> since the sidebar does it for you when you select the php option for it.

Comment: `$output = echo implode('<br />', $images);

return $output;`

Comment: TBH, I don't know what you're talking about. You may need return statements inside functions but this is not the case. Just copy and paste my code and it will work.

Comment: the sidebar I am working with allows you to insert php code into it, and I guess it automatically formats it. I am trying to edit a vBulletin sidebar. vBulletin provides instructions on how you should insert php code, my guess is because it adds the <?php> tags for you. What it says is that you need to run a code that can use a "return" statement, then that output the return statement provides will show up. Thats why it has to end in `return $my_output;` for example. When I switch it to an HTML sidebar, the images show up but so does the php code text, which means its not parsing it right.

Comment: as of right now, when I copy/paste your code it doesn't work at all. the page doesn't load anything where the sidebar usually is. Thank you for all of your help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Now I get it, you forgot to tell us about this important detail. I'm going to edit my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

After finding a nice introductory course to PHP (Google "php tutorial -w3schools" for a good tutorial on PHP).

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Google can tell you how to put your values in an array and neatly output that array using a foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry : ( It's where I've taught myself HTML/PHP/JS and the likes back in the days and I've turned out fine. (I don't mind reading 20 page long design theory/paradigm articles though) What would be a good alternative to point new people to?

Comment: Sorry, but if you follow that sites example your code will be a lot less than "fine"

Comment: That sites examples have long since been replaced by my own. Nevertheless your link has proven very helpful in removing w3schools from my search results so I can more easily find php.net's entries. (I don't see why W3schools is above that, annoying as hell).

Comment: Thanks guys. No, this is not homework. Its for my site, I just don't know much about PHP, well any really. I will check out some links and learn some more.